# Order of processing actions in local.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, css, local.xml, action

This is an extract from my **local.xml**:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addLinkRel">
        <rel>stylesheet</rel>
        <href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,600,700</href>
    </action>
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>css/custom-atf.css</name>
    </action>
    ...
</reference>
```

In the html source I would expect the google font link to appear before the custom-atf.css link but that is not the case. The google font link is being loaded almost last of all the scripts and css files.

Is there a specific order in which different actions in local.xml are processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For process order take a look at [`Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php#L162-L231):

- `getCssJsHtml()`-
- `_separateOtherHtmlHeadElements(...)`

I think load order is like:

- CSS
- JS
- other links

I guess its not possible by default and there is no block before `<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>` where you could inject it, so it seems you have to add it manually to your `\template\page\html\head.phtml`.

Comment: Thank you. I understand where those methods are coming from now. And yes, adding it to head.phtml works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addLinkRel">
        <rel>stylesheet</rel>
        <href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,600,700</href>
    </action>
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>css/custom-atf.css</name>
    </action>
    <action method="removeItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>css/custom-atf.css</name>
    </action>
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>css/custom-atf.css</name>
    </action>

    ...
</reference>
```

Comment: Surely that is just going to ensure that it gets added *after* custom-atf.css. I want it to appear *before* custom-atf.css in the html. Why do you think that will work?

Comment: I understood otherwise, please look my update now

Comment: That made no difference at all :( It feels as though Magento is processing actions in an order according to the method called.

Comment: I tested and it's works for me

Comment: Just to confirm... with only the first two actions the google font link is after custom-atf.css . Adding the 3rd and fourth actions loads the google font before custom-atf.css?

Comment: Same here ... maybe i've missed something, but have tried and did not work for me :(

Comment: @sv3n I don't know why, but it works for me, ok i'll delete my answer, however add it directly in `head.phtml` is not a good practice !

Comment: I'd also prefer a solution with layout updates, but it just did not work for me. Even checked N98_Layouthelper extension, but without success.

Comment: @sv3n ok, i delete it now